# How to keep the /blog slug even in single post slug

Tags: customization, permalinks, slug

I have a simple website on wordpress (latest version), assume example.org.

I wanna have the user posts at something like example.org/blog/username/posttitle.

So I need some levels:
1) example.org/blog (main blog page)
2) example.org/blog/username (username archive page)
3) example.org/blog/username/posttitle (single post page)

I've seen a lot of old solutions that are mainly the same, but even if i set the permalink structure as /blog/%author%/%postname% or simply /blog/%postname% it doesn't work.

I mean, it works, but when you visit a right generated url I get a 404.

Solutions?
Cheers,

Comment: Do you have installed a Multisite (network) version of WordPress?

Comment: Nope, i found that it was because i've also set the base category to 'blog' and it collides with the permalink structure. It works now.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, Now I have understand the question right. I have read, that you will remove the blog slug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your premalink setting page:
Use Custom structure and put in this `/blog/%author%/%postname%/` into the field. That should do the trick.

Comment: Are you sure you read the full post? I cite myself:

_I've seen a lot of old solutions that are mainly the same, but even if i set the permalink structure as /blog/%author%/%postname% or simply /blog/%postname% it doesn't work.

I mean, it works, but when you visit a right generated url I get a 404._. Thanks anyway, but it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I tested it out on my blog, and it worked. My WP version is 3.8

Comment: What do you mean a "right generated url"

Comment: I mean that the url is well done, accordingly with the permalink structure, but it falls in a 404.

Comment: Damn, i just found that it was because of i've set the base category to 'blog', it collides. My fault, it works.